# Why does PyTorch's max pooling layer store input tensors?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I made a simple model like below. It seems weird but it has one convolutional layer and two maxpooling layer.

```py
class simple_model(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self):
         super(simple_model, self).__init__()
         self.maxpool2D = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
         self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 20, (5, 5))

     def forward(self, x):
         x = self.maxpool2D(self.maxpool2D(self.conv1(x)))

         return x
```

And I check the tensors that saved in forward propagation using gradient hook.

```py
pack_saved_tensors = []
def pack_hook(x):
    saved_tensors.append(x)
    return x

unpack_used_tensors = []
def unpack_hook(x):
    unpack_used_tensors.append(x)
    return x

with torch.autograd.graph.saved_tensors_hooks(pack_hook, unpack_hook):
     model_output = model(input_tensors)

label = torch.randn(model_output.size()).to(device)
loss = criterion(model_output, label)
loss.backward()
```

This is the result. And I even checked that all stored tensors are used for backward propagation.(with unpack hook funciton) And I think,

0th, 1st tensors saved for convolutional layer,

2nd, 3rd tensors saved for first maxpool2D layer,

4th, 5th tensors saved for second maxpool2D layer.

```
pack hook saved tensors:
0 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 3, 224, 224]), tensor type: torch.float32
1 tensor size: torch.Size([20, 3, 5, 5]), tensor type: torch.float32
2 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 220, 220]), tensor type: torch.float32
3 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 110, 110]), tensor type: torch.int64
4 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 110, 110]), tensor type: torch.float32
5 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 55, 55]), tensor type: torch.int64

unpack hook used tensors:
6 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 110, 110]), tensor type: torch.float32
7 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 55, 55]), tensor type: torch.int64
8 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 220, 220]), tensor type: torch.float32
9 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 20, 110, 110]), tensor type: torch.int64
10 tensor size: torch.Size([64, 3, 224, 224]), tensor type: torch.float32
11 tensor size: torch.Size([20, 3, 5, 5]), tensor type: torch.float32
```

My question is:

Why Pytorch store input tensors for maxpooling layer? I think, in backward propagation max pooling layer only need to store int64 tensors(3rd, 5th layer which is store indices of max value).

Thank you for reading this long post.
Any help is appreciated.